# WiX ServiceControl Stop a service on uninstall, but don't start it on install

Tags: service, wix, windows-installer, installation, uninstallation

I need the service to stop and be removed on its uninstall, but I don't want it to start on install. The problem is, the start attribute on the `ServiceControl` element does not provide an option to disable starting. Or am I just missing it?

I'm using this for my service control element:

```
<ServiceControl Id="StartService"
    Start="install"
    Stop="both"
    Remove="uninstall"
    Name="Remec.AteService"
    Wait="yes" />
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html), the `start` attribute is optional, so simply omit it entirely.

```
 <ServiceControl Id="StartService"
    Stop="both"
    Remove="uninstall"
    Name="Remec.AteService"
    Wait="yes" />
```

Comment: It'd be nice if this were _in_ the documentation - I missed it too.  I'm also a bit confused by apparently being able to specify that the service be started on uninstall?

Comment: Starting a service on uninstall may make sense if you need to start a different service...

Comment: How to stop service during uninstall. I get the message "The following applications should be closed ...

Answer (score 6):

Leave out the `Start` attribute.