# How do I stop a service at the start of a wix installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm writing a Wix installer. The first step of this installer is to stop a Windows service. I found the Wix element `StopServices` in the `InstallExecuteSequence` that seems to do what I want, but I can't find any example usage of it. Specifically, I don't understand how the service name is specified.

How can I stop a service at the start of my Wix installation (and restart it at the end)?

Comment: Perhaps check these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590089/wix-servicecontrol-stop-a-service-on-uninstall-but-dont-start-it-on-install and http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2009/01/01/21.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The internal name (as opposed to the display name) of the service will work. On Windows 10 Task Manager they are the names in the Services tab - that shows the internal name. In the services applet (run services.msc) the properties of a service will show the name and the display name. If you installed the service with WiX ServiceInstall then the internal name is the Name that you used there.

Services have an internal name and a display name, as in the ServiceInstall table in an MSI that installs one:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637(v=vs.85).aspx

which is basically a list of parameters to the CreateService API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx

APIs and installers that do things to services use that internal name (Name in ServiceInstall and ServiceControl) because the display name is localizable but the internal name stays the same.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by internal name of the service. Where do I specify this name? Also, if it matters, this is a Windows server 2008